# alert option when It's selected

Tags: jquery

I want to alert the value or text of an option when I select it

how do I do that?

my code:

```
<select class="btn dropdown-toggle ddbtn"  required autofocus ><
    <option class="all" value="">Test</option>
    <option class="all" value="Test1">Test1</option>
    <option class="all" value="Test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".ddbtn").change(function(){
  alert($(".ddbtn").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="btn dropdown-toggle ddbtn"  required autofocus >
    <option class="all" value="">Test</option>
    <option class="all" value="Test1">Test1</option>
    <option class="all" value="Test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

With reference of the element which invokes the event by using 'this' keyword.

```
$(".ddbtn").click(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```